# HttpClient and MultipartEntity vs. Jersey Multipart and Android

Tags: android, httpclient, jersey, multipart

I have a rest webservice that takes a POST metod with multipart message:

```
@Path("transferFile")     
 @POST  
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)  
public String multipartTest(com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart data) {  
try {  
// get first body part (index 0)          
BodyPart bp = multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0);  
etc..
```

Now I am trying to write a java client for that. I started with a simple jersey client:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();  
    multiPart.bodyPart( new BodyPart(wavestream,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));  

    Client c = Client.create();  
    WebResource r = c.resource("http://127.0.0.1:8080/webapp:);
response=r.path("transferFile").type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(String.class, multiPart);
```

This works great - everything is ok. However I need this client working on Android and I have trouble with using jersey on that platform. So I used the normal way to send multipart message on android:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(90000)); // 90 second 

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8080/webapp/transferFile");
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA );

//tried with and without base64
 byte [] encodedWavestream = Base64.encodeBytesToBytes(wavestream);
 InputStream ins = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedWavestream);
 InputStreamBody body = new InputStreamBody(ins, "test" );
 int send = ins.available(); 

MultipartEntity requestContent = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE ); 
requestContent.addPart("stream", body);

httpPost.setEntity(requestContent); 
HttpResponse Response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

An this gives an annoying response from the server :

```
HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request  
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request).
```

I check the server log files but there is nothing there. So I don't know what's the origin of this error. I have wrote a simple html page with a post formula and 'multipart/form-data' content-type and it also works! An auto-generated request from soapUI also works! Why my client does not work? Can anybody help?

Comment: I assume you are using android Emulator and application Server on the same host. In that case you must use 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 to reach the host system ! Otherwise you point to the virtual (emulated) device itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in Jersey. See [Chunked encoding problem](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Chunked-encoding-problem-td4742270.html).

This problem appears only for few clients (iOS, Android).

If you set the Content-Type to application/octet-stream, then the Jersey MessageWriter for the application/octet-stream will set the Content-Length and 
not send as chunked transport method.

There is [solution](http://davidbuccola.blogspot.com/2009/09/configure-jersey-chunked-encoding-when.html) for Jersey Client:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, 32 * 1024);
```

But it doesn't work for the **iOS's or Android's client**.
So I tested Apache File Upload. Threre was another bug: "Stream ended unexpectedly".

Only **[Oreilly upload](http://www.servlets.com/cos/)** can upload file correct for all clients.
This is my code:

```
public Object[] getParametersAndFiles(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    log.debug("OreillyUpload");
    Properties params = new Properties();
    LinkedHashMap files = new LinkedHashMap();

    File tempDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")); 

    MultipartParser mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); // 10MB
    Part part;
    while ((part = mp.readNextPart()) != null) {
        String name = part.getName();
        if (part.isParam()) {
            // it's a parameter part
            ParamPart paramPart = (ParamPart) part;
            String value = paramPart.getStringValue();
            params.put(name, value);

            log.debug("param; name=" + name + ", value=" + value);
        }
        else if (part.isFile()) {
            // it's a file part
            FilePart filePart = (FilePart) part;
            String fileName = filePart.getFileName();
            if (fileName != null) {
                // the part actually contained a file
                File file = new File(tempDirectory,fileName);
                long size = filePart.writeTo(file);
                files.put(name, file);

                log.debug("file; name=" + name + "; filename=" + fileName +
                        ", filePath=" + filePart.getFilePath() +
                        ", content type=" + filePart.getContentType() +
                        ", size=" + size);

            }
            else {
                // the field did not contain a file
                log.debug("file; name=" + name + "; EMPTY");
            }
        }
    }

    return new Object[] {params, files};
}
```

And this is Jersey Server code (warning all Jersey Upload anotations (like as "@FormDataParam") should be removed):

```
@POST
@Path("uploadMarkup")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
////    public void uploadMarkup(
//    public JSONWithPadding uploadMarkup(
//            @FormDataParam("markupFile") InputStream markupFile,
//            @FormDataParam("markupFile") FormDataContentDisposition details,
//            @FormDataParam("slideNum") int slideNum) {
public JSONWithPadding uploadMarkup(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object[] data = uploadService.getParametersAndFiles(request);
    ...
}
```